# Why program is terminated if neither calls std::thread::detach nor std::thread::join?

Tags: c++, stdthread

I know that if there is neither `std::thread::detach` nor `std::thread::join` is called. The thread object calls `std::terminate` within the destructor. I am wondering what the design choose of this? Why it calls `std::terminate`n within destructor. Furthermore, if it doesn't call `std::terminate` within the destructor, the behavior of no-detach is the same as what detach behaves now. So why not only keeps `thread::join` and remove the calling of terminate when design thread API? What the consideration under the hood?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was the subject of much debate pre-C++11.

Your question makes a bold assumption: that detachment is obviously the correct behavior. But you never substantiate it. Indeed, there are many arguments against this idea, and the committee considered them.

I'll take this example from the paper [outlining the argument against it](https://wg21.link/N2802):

```
int fib(int n) {
    if (n <= 1) return n;
    int fib1, fib2;
    
    std::thread t([=, &fib1]{fib1 = fib(n-1);});
    fib2 = fib(n-2);
    if (fib2 < 0) throw ...
    t.join();
    return fib1 + fib2;
}
```

Once you start throwing exceptions around, the default detachment behavior stops being so useful. Indeed, you can imagine a more complex case, where the exception comes from something non-local to the thread creation routine. Consider [this example from a later paper](https://wg21.link/P0206R0):

```
      std::vector<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>> partitions =
        utils::partition_indexes(0, size-1, num_threads);
      std::vector<std::thread> threads;

      LOG(LOG_DEBUG, "controller::reload_all: starting reload threads...");
      for (unsigned int i=0; i<num_threads-1; i++) {
        threads.push_back(std::thread(reloadrangethread(this,
        partitions[i].first, partitions[i].second, size, unattended)));
      }

      LOG(LOG_DEBUG, "controller::reload_all: starting my own reload...");
      this->reload_range(partitions[num_threads-1].first,
        partitions[num_threads-1].second, size, unattended);

      LOG(LOG_DEBUG, "controller::reload_all: joining other threads...");
      for (size_t i=0; i<threads.size(); i++) {
        threads[i].join();
      }
```

`push_back` can fail due to lack of memory for reallocating the array. If that happens, you lose access to all of those threads, and your program is broken.

Both of these scenarios lead to a broken program, whether you default to detach or default to `terminate`. But if the program is going to be broken, it's best that it be broken *immediately* when the issue occurs, rather than at some later location in the code.

Now, the *safer* solution is to `join` in the destructor. But that didn't happen for various other reasons. The (unfortunate) consensus was that, if you didn't say what you want to do, then your code is broken and should blow up.

Fortunately, C++20 gave us `std::jthread`, which joins by default in its destructor.

The general idea of `std::thread`'s destructor behavior is very simple:

1. The user didn't say what to do (ie: didn't call `join` or `detach`).
2. Neither answer is obviously the right one.

You claim that simply doing a `detach` is the right solution. But why is it right? Detachment is a very unsafe thing to do since you lose the ability to `join` with the thread ever again.

There's also the issue of RAII. An exception could cause some `thread` object to be destroyed unintentionally. If that happens, and the default behavior is to detach, is your program still in a functional state? What if the rest of your program was expecting to `join` those threads, and now that's impossible?

Answer (score 1):

Losing threads is bad; your program’s shutdown becomes very crashy in almost every platform (I mean you can get lucky...).

Detached threads can be not lost via the "make ready at thread exit" futures.  But calling `detach()` without arranging for a way to synchronize the end of your thread to occur before the end of `main()` means your program’s behaviour probably becomes undefined by the C++ standard (most code in most threads is full of code that cannot safely be run after main ends, so threads alive after the end of `main()` are not a good idea; without a join or equivalent, there is a "race" between thread finishing and `main()` doing so, no matter how many "sleep" calls you make.  The existence of such a race is usually enough to make C++ formally write off specifying the behaviour of your program).

The idea that "I should just detach" is wrong.  The idea that threads should default to `detach()` is crazy.

Defaulting to `join()` is a more reasonable position than `detach()`.  But joining **can throw**.  Throwing in destructors is bad, because they are evaluated during throws themselves, and if the code involved in unwinding during a throw in turn throws then the program terminates.  What more, that exception path, if unexamined, is likely to contain deadlock conditions, as you might be half way through a handshake with another thread and it doesn't know to shut itself down.

`std::thread` is not a user-friendly safe threading primitive; making threads user-friendly is far beyond its scope.  User-friendly safe threading primitives can be built on top of it.  It is one step removed from a raw pthread.  As an example, libraries like IPP or the like.  What it does is make writing threaded code **possible** in C++ without platform-specific extensions.

By terminating when destroyed, we provide feedback to the programmer during the design phase that they have to intelligently deal with the issues, and not ignore them.  This makes it a tiny bit harder to use, but 99.9% of the difficulty of proper use of threads isn't calling `join()`.

Threading is **hard** to get right.  It also tends to usually-work-ok when you get it wrong; then it locks up or crashes rarely, and only on some other user’s system with symbols stripped.  You cannot rely on "I tried it and it worked" once you add threading to a program.  You cannot even usually rely on "this code is locally correct", because most concurrency designs don't **compose** - three pairwise "correct" subprograms can, when combined, become incorrect.

Libraries like TBB or the like, or roll your own, can reduce this issue a little bit.  As can immutable state and functional operations.  Or a bunch of other rigorous design stuff.  All of which end up involving writing a framework on top of something as low level as `std::thread`.

Answer (score 1):

*This is a half-answer, focusing only on "why not detach".*

A `std::thread` represents a thread of execution. Going by the RAII paradigm, the constructor creates the thread of execution, and the destructor destroys it (with appropriate caveats for "empty" objects that do not currently represent a thread of execution). Detaching from a thread does not end the thread of execution, so that is not a good conceptual fit for the destructor.

Joining a thread waits for the end of the thread of execution, while termination forces the end of the thread of execution. Either of these approaches is a conceptual match to the destructor of `std::thread`. I'll leave it up to others to discuss why one option was chosen over the other. (The short version is that there was much debate; neither option is unquestionably better than the other, yet a decision had to be made.)

*Better answers have been given by others. I offer this answer for those looking for something brief and conceptual.*